# Simple single page application is not running

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `angular.js` and I was trying my hands on it. Can anyone please tell me why this program is not running?

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@>=1.9.1 <3" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.45" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.45/angular2.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <br/>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS code:**

```
// Code goes here
var demoApp = angular.module ('demoApp', []);
function SimpleController($scope){
  $scope.customers=[
    {name:'xx xx' city:'xx'},
    {name:'yy yy' city:'yy'},
    {name:'zz zz' city:'zz'}
    ];
}
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
```

Comment: Please write what you are trying to achieve and what seems to be the problem. Don't expect developers to go over your code when your question is too wide.

Comment: @any error or display nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in you sample:

1. The main problem is that you're using the `Angular 1.x.x` syntax while you have the `Angular 2.x.x` script included in your app. Change the script for the previous release of the framework.

   ```
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
   ```
2. The customers object is not a valid JSON as separation commas between properties are missing. It should look like this:

   ```
   $scope.customers=[
       {name:'parikshit mishra', city:'jaipur'},
       {name:'nirmal vatsyayan', city:'delhi'},
       {name:'ningning numeyi', city:'noida'}
   ];
   ```
3. You don't show anything using `ng-repeat` directive, you simply create several empty `<li>` tags, hence there's no content inside them. You need to display the variable that you iterate. If you want to show only the name property of the object, use simple dot syntax.

   ```
   <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{cust.name}}</li>
   ```
4. Your input filed has `ng-model` attached, but you don't use the variable that is bound to it. You can refer to the variable with `{{name}}`.

   ```
   Name: {{name}}<br/>
   <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
   ```

To see the big picture, [here's the fixed sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/rWnt4bMEo7EvQycSjAa1?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

HTML

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
      Name: <br/>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
      <br/>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers| filter:name">{{cust}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Angular

```
var demoApp = angular.module ('demoApp', []);
function SimpleController($scope){
  $scope.customers=[
    {name:'parikshit mishra', city:'jaipur'},
    {name:'nirmal vatsyayan', city:'delhi'},
    {name:'ningning numeyi', city:'noida'}
  ];
}
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);
```

Please [refer](http://plnkr.co/edit/6VtHVdeMhKj2VESMqFB2?p=preview)

**Problem**

1. `$scope.customers` is not a valid `object`(missing commas between properties).
2. You have not displayed anything inside `ng-repeat`. Please use `{{cust}}`. Please refer [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).
3. The scripts inside your plunker are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34zv23nL/).

**js**

```
$scope.customers=[
{name:'parikshit mishra', city:'jaipur'},
{name:'nirmal vatsyayan', city:'delhi'},
{name:'ningning numeyi', city:'noida'}
];
```

**html**

```
  <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">
    {{ cust.name }}
  </li>
```

hope this will help you